# C# Mvc CurrentCulture async issue, wrong language loaded

Tags: c#, asynchronous, model-view-controller, culture, currentculture

I've currently an issue with switching languages in MVC while using async

This works fine :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr");
    return View("Index");
}
```

This code won't work 
(when using async, it will keep my default language nl, while it's set to fr):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr");
    return View("Index");
}
```

Any idea why my @Resource won't work when using async and how i could solve this?  (for keeping a better overview, i didn't include my await stuff within the code)

Many thanks already!

**Edit:** 
I've found some solution, but i'm not sure if it could provide some issues when multiple users are looking on the same page? 
https://weblogs.asp.net/morteza/how-to-set-currentculture-for-all-threads-in-a-domain-in-net-4-5

Kind regards,
Kurt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep CurrentCulture in async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30662668/keep-currentculture-in-async-await)

Comment: I think you are facing some error during your await task. check if your task is being completed?

Comment: Hi Elyas,

Thanks for your response.
https://weblogs.asp.net/morteza/how-to-set-currentculture-for-all-threads-in-a-domain-in-net-4-5

I think it's more related to this, but i'm not sure on how trustworthy this solution is.

Kind regards,
Kurt