# Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture changes .net 4.8 when async is used

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, culture

I started to use async operations in my WPF application and realized that Buttons, Labels are on the correct culture (hu-HU), but MessageBox.Show works on the culture of the operating system (en-US). I have resource files for both languages.

App.OnStartup contains

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("hu-HU");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("hu-HU");
```

When I press a button in my application and go to the VM I see that `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` is changed to "en-US" (`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` remained "hu-HU"). I understand this was an issue before .net 4.6 (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30664385/5852947) but it should not be in 4.8. As I understand https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netcore-3.1#Async states the both culture should be inherited from the originating thread.

I also tried this without success.

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("hu-HU");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("hu-HU");
```

UPDATE 1

I have a WPF application and I set the culture in `OnStartup()`. The culture is not hard coded I just wanted to simplify the code.
[image]
On the image you can see that the gui is in Hungarian but when I press a button and the corresponding `ICommand` run in the VM then `CurrentUICulture` is not correct. In debug mode at the execution of `ICommand` I also see that `CurrentUICulture` is not correct. I only set the culture in `App.OnStartup`. I had no problem until I did not use async. I changed `OnStartup()` to async because at one point it contains `await`.

```
    protected async override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs startupEventArgs)
    {
            base.OnStartup(startupEventArgs);
            var cultureString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Language"];
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(cultureString);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(cultureString);
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(cultureString);
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(cultureString);
            var mainWindowView = new MainWindowView();
            // ...
            mainWindowView.Show();
            ScrollDownInTableTab(mainWindowViewModel);            
    }
```

Comment: Post your actual async code. Where do you set the culture, where is it changed? Background operations run on a *threadpool* thread, which isn't affected by the UI thread's culture.

Comment: BTW if the user's locale is `en-US`, why hard-code `hu-HU`? Only developers use `en-US` outside the US itself. End users expect the application to use *their* choice

Comment: `I press a button in my application and go to the VM` what does that mean? Are you running the WPF app in that VM? `Buttons, Labels are on the correct culture (hu-HU)` in that case `CurrentUICulture` *hasn't* changed. Do you have some other code that tries to switch cultures? Were you trying to parse date or number literals in the US format by changing the thread culture perhaps?

Comment: `async override void OnStartup` ? `async void` is only meant for asynchronous event handlers. They're essentially fire-and-forget methods. This isn't an event handler. This method is *not* awaited by the rest of the application, so the rest of the application keeps without waiting for `OnStartup` to complete. Since `async void` methods aren't awaited, the application may be doing anything when that `await` returns. It may even have terminated, resulting in some weird errors. Most likely, ambient information like CultureInfo isn't preserved, precisely because the method isn't awaited

Comment: Any asynchronous operation in `OnStartup` would have to block, move somewhere else, or get awaited at a different method. What does this operation do?

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos. Changing back `OnStartup` solved the issue. I assumed if there is `async void Main` then there should be `async void OnStartup`. And it worked except the culture. I went back to the original functionality when the first access of the Db returned a `Task` and I use `Wait()` on it.

Comment: @IstvanHeckl: You shouldn't call `Wait()` on a task on the UI thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `Wait()` on a task blocks and potentially also deadlocks. Don't do this. A task represents an asynchronous operation that should be awaited.

As for the issue with culture, you can switch back to the old behaviour by setting the `NoAsyncCurrentCulture` switch to true in your `App.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8"/>
    </startup>
    <runtime>
        <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Globalization.NoAsyncCurrentCulture=true"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi @mm8
Your suggestion solves the culture issue, thank you. [According to this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/retargeting/4.5.2-4.6#currentculture-and-currentuiculture-flow-across-tasks) this is a workaround rather than a solution. It says I should set explicitly the culture in each async Task. Does it mean I should do this after each await? (I am using .net framework 4.8)

Comment: Hi @mm8   Your solution worked until now but I just upgraded to .net5. In the `OnStartup` of a WPF application I set `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` and `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` but if I start a click event or a command from a `Button` then `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` turns back to `en-US`. I can set it to the desired Culture but it must be done at each command. Do you have a better idea?

Comment: This is the solution in [.net 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70201743/5852947)

Comment: Been looking so long for the right answer for my .NET 4.8 solution with WPF, thanks so much!