# Setting Culture in .net5 WPF application

Tags: wpf, .net-5, culture

In a WPF application I try to set the culture in `OnStartup`.

```
    protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs startupEventArgs)
    {
        base.OnStartup(startupEventArgs);
        var a = new CultureInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Language"]);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = a;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = a;            
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = a
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = a;
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = a;
    }
```

If I start a method from the `MainWindow` with `Click` event or with `ICommand` then in the method the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` will be always `en-US`, which is very strange (can sombody exaplain?). I can set again to the desired `Culture` but I have to do it in each called method one by one. Is there an alternative?

In .net4.7 there was a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64263551/5852947) but it does not work in .net5.

Comment: Is there a reason why the `OnStartup` method is `async`? I can reproduce the problem with the `async` keyword, but if I remove it, then the correct Culture is set and strings are formatted using that Culture. So if it is not needed, maybe just remove the `async` part?

Comment: @LarsKristensen There's no `await` operator being used, so I'm perplexed as to how/why that could make a difference...

Comment: @Dai I'm not too familiar with asynchronous programming, so I don't know how or why either - but if I set a breakpoint in the `async`  version of the `OnStartup` method, it gets hit and the Culture is set - it just doesn't work afterwards, when the main window is loaded. But still, I would like to know a reason for `OnStartup` to be `async` in the first place - in what scenario can that be useful?

Comment: @LarsKristensen The `OnStartup` is much longer actually, I shortened it for brevity. The omitted part has `await` in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is how `async` methods are implemented. `async` methods have their own special execution context. This context has it's own `CultureInfo`, which is inherited from the non-async context that invokes the `async` method.
In your case, the `async` context's culture is inherited from the main thread, *before* the culture is changed.

What you can do is to implement the already suggested solution using the `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` to postpone the CultureInfo configuration. This way the configuration is executed outside the `async` context:

```
Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-EN"));
```

Since this can mess up your initialization routine, as the real context would be avaailable after the application is configured and the main Window displayed, you would prefer a different solution.

You can for example used an event based initialization routine, where you run low-level application configuration like culture configuration first and continue with the remaining initialization that involves asynchronous operations in an `async` context:

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
// Event may be defined on a different class
private event EventHandler ConfigurationCompleted;
private void OnConfigurationCompleted() => this.ConfigurationCompleted?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs startupEventArgs)
{
  this.ConfigurationCompleted += ConfigureInAsyncContext;

  // Do "low-level" application configuration. Code may be executed in a different class context

  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-EN");

  ...

  // Continue in async context
  OnConfigurationCompleted();
}
 
private async void ConfigureInAsyncContext(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // TODO::Execute async operations

  new MainWindow().Show();
}
```

The key is to separate the non-async configuration from the async initialization.